# Checking composite primary exists or not?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `Basket` that has a composite primary key `CustID` and `ProductID`, with 1 more attribute `Quantity`. `@custID` and `@productID` are passed to a stored procedure.

**I need to first check whether these 2 parameters already exists as composite PK or not, if NOT then I want to insert whole record by setting PK with parameters and increase quantity by 1.**

If the record already exist then I simply need to update quantity column by 1.

I am having tough time in checking and inserting the bold text. 
If someone know the solution kindly guide me please.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomething    
   @CustID INT, @ProductID INT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- check if that row already exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Basket 
               WHERE CustID = @CustID 
                 AND ProductID = @ProductID)
        -- if it exists - update "Quantity" by 1
        UPDATE dbo.Basket
        SET Quantity = Quantity + 1
        WHERE CustID = @CustID 
          AND ProductID = @ProductID)
    ELSE
        -- if it does not yet exist - create new row
        INSERT INTO dbo.Basket(CustomerID, ProductID, Quantity)
        VALUES (@CustID, @ProductID, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2008+ you can use

```
MERGE Basket WITH (HOLDLOCK)
USING (VALUES (
               @custID,
               @productID)) AS Source(CustID, ProductID)
ON Basket.CustID = Source.CustID
   AND Basket.ProductID = Source.ProductID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Quantity += 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CustID,
          ProductID,
          Quantity)
  VALUES (CustID,
          ProductID,
          1);
```